# ECMA 1 '~' punctuator example

Tags: javascript

I read ECMA documentation an found the `~` symbol in punctuators list.

When I should use this punctuator?

[image]

Comment: Isn’t this just the bitwise not operator?

Comment: see https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

Comment: I see, you’ve asked about the `&` operator about half an hour ago as well. Seriously, the link to all the operators is _right there_ at the top of this post and you could’ve simply searched for any basic JS tutorial with an overview of operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ a - Inverts the bits of its operand.